# Limit and order by rand - in groups

Tags: mysql, random, limit

Maybe I am confused, but I seem to be on the wrong way to find a solution right now.

I would like to select random data from a table, but with some limits
Let's say the table has a NAME and AGE...10.000 rows

I would like to select (in that order)

- 2 random people that are older than 60 years
- 2 random people that are older than 40 years (includes over 60 too)
- 2 random people at any age.

And of course all distinct.

Result

```
Andy 77
Maria 64
Harry 54
Fritz 62
Anna 24
Moses 43
```

What's your best solution?

I though UNION and LIMIT would work with ORDER BY RAND()...but no..not allowed
Order by with limits?

Ok, in a perfect world this would work

```
select name, age from persons where age >60 order by rand() limit 2 
UNION 
select name, age from persons where age >40 order by rand() limit 2 
UNION 
select name, age from persons where 1 order by rand() limit 2
```

(it does not of course) and it includes the erroer that there the selection could include 2 times the same person...

So how do I solve it?

select name, age from persons order by case when age >60 then 'a' limit 2 when age >40 then 'b' limit 2 else 1 limit 'c' asc

that does not work too of course..

Comment: I don't get this you could end up with a result set with no one in the 0-60 range -is that ok? ie conditions 2 and 3 might all be over 60.

Comment: why no one?
There are enough people in every age group.

I want to show first: 2 >60, then 2 over 40 and then 2 random...(every age)

Comment: btw, yes it is okay to have no one in that group...

Comment: Without putting each `select ...` between braces, the example code may not work. `(select name, age from persons where age >60 order by rand() limit 2 )
UNION 
(select name, age from persons where age >40 order by rand() limit 2)
UNION 
(select name, age from persons where 1 order by rand() limit 2)`

Comment: the example would never work, mysql does not allow order by rand() with limit and UNION

Comment: @bodomalo The code post above can solve your question partially. The left question is how to eliminate the duplicate element in the result of three `select` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but I think it works:

```
select t.name, t.age
from (
  select * from (
    select t.name, t.age, min(t.ingroup) ingroup
    from (
      select * from (
        select name, age, 1 ingroup from tablename
        where age > 60
        order by rand() limit 2
      ) t1
      union all
      select * from (
        select name, age, 2 ingroup from tablename
        where age > 40
       order by rand() limit 4
      ) t2
    ) t  
    group by t.name, t.age
    order by ingroup limit 4
  ) g12
  union all
  select * from (
    select name, age, 3 ingroup from tablename
    order by rand() limit 8
  ) g3
) t
group by t.name, t.age
order by min(t.ingroup) limit 6
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a92QXKosDK3EnYjSnPXQwp/3) (I added more rows to your sample data).